# Erro ao carregar imagem que vem do servidor

Tags: node.js, angular, express.js

Olá, estou tentando carregar a imagem que está no meu servidor direto para a interface. O servidor é nodejs com express, já no front-end estou usando o sanitizer do angular.

No servidor eu tenho:

```
server.js: 
    app.use(express.json());
```

```
routes.js:
    routes.get('/user_img/id', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const img = req.params.id;
        res.status(200).send(`./tmp/uploads/${img}`);
    }
    catch (e) {
        res.status(404).json({error: 'Image not found'});
    }
});
```

A resposta da requisição é essa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No angular eu tenho:

```
HTML:
    <img class="user" [src]="user?.imgUser | safeHtml" alt="avatar"/>
```

```
SafeHtmlPipe:
    @Pipe({
        name: 'safeHtml'
    })
    export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

        constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        }

        transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
           return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
        }

    }
```

```
component.ts: 
    this.userService.getImage(nome da imagem).then(
          (image) => {
                const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(image);
                this.user.imgUser = URL.createObjectURL(imageURL);
          }, error => {
                console.log(error);
          }
     );
```

```
UserService: 
    getImage(nome da imagem) {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/user_img/(nome da imagem)`).toPromise();
    }
```

A saida no console é:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Em:
UserService:
getImage(nome da imagem) {
return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/user_img/(nome da imagem)`).toPromise();
}

Altere o sinal de acento crase para spas simples.

Comment: Estou tentando concatenar uma string com variáveis, não sei como isso pode ajudar mas vou tentar

Comment: como eu disse, a rota não é encontrada porque estou concatenando como é mostrado nesse print [link](https://prnt.sc/u86quu)